# Use the extreme values of scale_colour_brewer palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable number of columns that I'd like to plot with `scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn").` If I have five columns, the colors I get for the highest and lowest factors are dark green and dark red.

```
n <- 5 #number of variables
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10*n)
cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2)  +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")  + theme_bw()
```

[image]
However, if I only have two columns (`n <- 2`), I get middle of the range colors. How can I get dark red and dark green for the highest and lowest factor no matter how many columns in my data?

```
n <- 2 #number of variables
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10*n)
cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2)  +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")  + theme_bw()
```

[image]

**EDIT**
In the end, I modified @paqmo 's answer and used `seq`. By default, `seq` chooses the extreme values and fills the inbetween.

```
n <- 2#number of variables
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10*n)
cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
            geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2) +
            scale_colour_manual(values = brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn")[round(seq(from = 1, to = 11,length.out = n))] ) +
            theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scale_colour_manual` instead to choose which values from the palette you want. You have to make sure you load `Rcolorbrewer` when you do this, as `ggplot2` only calls `Rcolorbrewer` when you use the `scale_colour_brewer` argument. `colorRampPalette` grabs colors from the brewer palette.

```
set.seed(1034)
n <- 2 #number of variables
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10*n)
cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"), bias = 2)(n)) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
 set.seed(1034)
    n <- 3 #number of variables
    x <- 1:10
    y <- runif(10*n)
    cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
    df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

    ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2) +   
        scale_colour_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"), bias = 2)(n)) +
        theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
 set.seed(1034)
        n <- 4 #number of variables
        x <- 1:10
        y <- runif(10*n)
        cond <- rep(1:n, each = 10)
        df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

        ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
            geom_line(aes(colour=factor(cond), group=factor(cond)),size=2) +
            scale_colour_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"), bias = 2)(n)) +
            theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does not work with `n <- 5`. I need a solution that gives me the colors at the extremes of the range independently of how many columns I have to plot.

Comment: Missed that, sloppy on my part. `colorRampPalette` will help, use `bias` to adjust where it grabs colors from the palette.

Comment: In the end, I modified your answer to use a `seq`. By default, `seq` will use the extreme values and fill the inbetween. `scale_colour_manual(values = brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn")[round(seq(from = 1, to = 11,length.out = n))] )`.

Answer (score 2):

You can hack it by setting fewer breaks than limits:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(47)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                  y = runif(20), 
                  cond = factor(rep(1:2, each = 10)))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = cond)) +
    geom_line(size = 2)  +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", 
                        breaks = 1:2, 
                        limits = seq(1,2, length.out = 5))
```

[image]